# Invalid number of returned comma delimited string in a IN clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery, in-clause, ora-01722

I am trying to use a subquery that returns a comma delimited string in a IN clause.

The following way:

```
SELECT p.person_id, g.name || '>>' || p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname as GROUP_PATH
FROM PERSON p 
LEFT JOIN GROUP g ON (
    g.group_id = p.group_id
)
WHERE p.person_id IN ( 
    SELECT person_ids FROM other WHERE other_id = :OTHER_ID
) 
ORDER BY lower(GROUP_PATH)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number.

Is there a better way to do this or even possible?

Comment: Can you show the table definition (particularly the id column types) for all three tables; and how `:other_id` is defined? You may be joining a number column to a varchar that you think only has numbers, or only matches on numbers, and it's tripping over a non-numeric value you aren't expecting to be relevant.

Comment: I just noticed that my initial query was wrong. I updated it.

Comment: Is `person_ids` in `other` a comma-separated list?  If so, that's not going to work in an `IN` clause.  You'd need to parse the string into a collection and use the collection in the query.  But you should never be storing a comma-separated list of keys in a relational database in the first place so you probably want to fix your data model.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious explanation is that you are trying to do math with a string...

> The attempted conversion of a
>   character string to a number failed
>   because the character string was not a
>   valid numeric literal. Only numeric
>   fields or character fields containing
>   numeric data may be used in arithmetic
>   functions or expressions. Only numeric
>   fields may be added to or subtracted
>   from dates.

http://ora-01722.ora-code.com/

**Update #1:**

Your description worries me:

> I am trying to use a subquery that
>   returns a comma delimited string in a
>   IN clause.

Your subquery should *not* return a comma delimited string (unless `g.group_id` is a string and expects a comma delimited string). You must retrieve individual items in as many rows as needed (less than 1,000 anyway).

**Update #2:**

Just to make it clear:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
) FOO;

FOO_ID                 
---------------------- 
1                      
2                      
3
```

You can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
) FOO
WHERE FOO_ID IN (1, 2);

FOO_ID                 
---------------------- 
1                      
2
```

But not this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
) FOO
WHERE FOO_ID IN ('1,2');

SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Because you cannot compare number `1` with string `'1,2'`. Subqueries follow similar rules:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
) FOO
WHERE FOO_ID IN (
    SELECT 1 AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
);

FOO_ID                 
---------------------- 
1                      
2 

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
) FOO
WHERE FOO_ID IN (
    SELECT '1,2' AS FOO_ID FROM DUAL
);

SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: When I only query the subquery and paste the results (comma delimited) into the IN clause it works fine. Any explanation for that?

Comment: Let's say you get `'10,20,30'`. What do you do with it? `g.group_id IN (10,20,30)` (three numbers) or `g.group_id IN ('10,20,30')` (one string)?

Comment: I noticed that I rewrote the query wrong. Check it out now.

I am supposed to get multiple person_ids and not group_ids.

Comment: Doesn't really matter; are the multiple IDs returned as a string?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so, because the column person_ids is of the type varchar2.

Comment: In which case you need to look at Justin's answer to break the string into individual numeric values that can be joined to your numeric `person_id` column.

Comment: Thanks you. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum, in order to reference the alias `GROUP_PATH`, you would need to need to use a nested subquery where the alias is defined before you reference it in your ORDER BY clause.  That's realistically not causing the ORA-01722 error, but it is a problem

```
SELECT group_id, group_path
  FROM (SELECT g.group_id, 
               g.name || '>>' || p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname as GROUP_PATH
          FROM PERSON p 
               LEFT JOIN GROUP g ON (
                      g.group_id = p.group_id
               )
         WHERE p.person_id IN ( 
               SELECT person_ids FROM other WHERE other_id = :OTHER_ID
               ) 
 ORDER BY lower(GROUP_PATH)
```

If the `PERSON_IDS` column in the `OTHER` table is a comma separated list of values, your IN list is not going to do what you'd expect.  You would need to transform the scalar string (that happens to have commas in it) into some sort of collection of multiple PERSON_ID values.  There are various approaches to doing this, Tom Kyte has one example of using a [variable IN list](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425).  Assuming you copy Tom's IN_LIST function, you should be able to do something like

```
SELECT group_id, group_path
  FROM (SELECT g.group_id, 
               g.name || '>>' || p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname as GROUP_PATH
          FROM PERSON p 
               LEFT JOIN GROUP g ON (
                      g.group_id = p.group_id
               )
         WHERE p.person_id IN ( 
               SELECT column_value
                 FROM TABLE(SELECT in_list(person_ids) 
                              FROM other 
                             WHERE other_id = :OTHER_ID)
               ) 
 ORDER BY lower(GROUP_PATH)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Justin. I just noticed that I wrote the query wrong. Instead of getting a comma delimited string of group ids, I am getting comma delimited ids of persons.

Comment: @Kel - Edited my queries to match